# Comparison between best defense moves

Tags: sicilian-defense, french-defense

I am a novice player. I have just come across the Sicilian defense on the Internet which is also stated as "aggressive defense". The French defense (1.e4 e6) also is good. Does the French defense cramp Black's position in the midgame as a result of which it is considered next to Sicilian ? Because I find the French defense to be structurally more organised than the Sicilian.

Comment: I would kindly ask the downvoter the reason for giving me a -1. The phrase "next to Sicilian" means that Sicilian defense is given  more priority by the players in comparison to French defense. I hope you have understood @Lourens.

Comment: The openings kinda come as a matter of style basically. So many openings are feasible and demand different play styles. People that play french like its closed structural style. I didnt quite understand what was it that you were asking. Are you asking if the french defense gives you a cramped position ? Or are you asking if the french is the second most played opening as black ? Or are you asking something else ?

Comment: I like French the most. However results on the internet show that Sicilian defense is favoured by many players( Black) . The French defense occupies the second position . What has led to the French defense occupying the second position? This is my question and I hope it is crystal clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what you exactly mean with `it is considered next to the Sicilian`. However, first of all, I would like to state that the `Sicilian Defense` is not always aggressive. It depends on the line you play. Often, if White castles Queenside, the game becomes very sharp. However, if White castles Kingside, the game often becomes less sharp.

The biggest problem with the `French Defence` is the development of Black's White Squared Bishop. The French has either very sharp lines and less sharp lines, such as `1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 exd5`, known as the `Exchange Variation`.

But in general, both openings can be really aggressive. You could take a look at:

For the `Sicilian Defense`:

`Sicilian Defense, Dragon Variation, Yugoslav Attack`

`Sicilian Defense, Dragadorf Variation`

`Sicilian Defense, Najdorf Variation, English Attack`

And for the `French Defense`:

`French Defense, Winawer, Poisoned Pawn Variation`.
`French Defense, King's Indian Attack`.

Again, I'm not sure what answer you're looking for, but I believe that these (aggressive) lines may be very helpful comparing them. Seeing games (especially of higher-rated players, such as GMs, makes the opening-ideas a lot more clear, so I suggest doing that.

Comment: Lourens please upvote the question

Comment: @AkashRoy Why should Lourens Dijkstra be required to upvote your question?

Comment: User is the question of low quality?